# Automatically sync my app from F-Droid to Google Play

Tags: open-source, play-store

I am developing a popular Android app. It is published to F-Droid and Google Play.

I want a program that detects when F-Droid has been updated, and automatically sync from F-Droid to Google Play:

- Push the APK downloaded from F-Droid
- Update the Google Play description using F-Droid's description/metadata

---

*Why sync from F-Droid rather than push to Google Play manually? To ensure that only open source code makes it to Google Play.*

Comment: I doubt this has been done, but I really like the idea. Maybe explore the Google Play Console APIs?

Comment: It's been proposed to have it built into F-Droid but seems like it hasn't been started yet. https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidserver/issues/143 (~9mo age)

Comment: It's implemented now

Comment: @janot: Could you please provide a link proving that? Thanks!

Comment: I thought comment above mine contains link? I haven't tried it, sorry if it's actually not what you wanted.